# True or false: There exists a series $\sum_n a_n$ of non-negative terms that is convergent, such that $\sum (a_n)^{5/6} $ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis

So far I'm thinking that we can use a p-series, $$\sum \frac{1}{n^p},$$ which converges if and only if $p>1$. How would I then show the series where each term is raised to the power of $5/6$ diverges? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use that $p$-series for any $p \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$1 < p \leq 1.2$$

The resulting $p$-series will have terms

$$\frac{1}{n} >a_n \geq \frac{1}{n^{1.2}}$$

And the series with terms raised to the $5/6^{\text{th}}$ power, will have

$$\left(a_n\right)^{5/6}\geq\frac{1}{n}$$

The former converges because it is a $p$-series with $p>1$. The latter diverges because it is a $p$-series with $p\leq 1$. You can also see that the second series diverges because its terms are all at least as big as the terms of the Harmonic series, and that series diverges.

Answer (score 3):

$\sum \dfrac{1}{n^{6/5}}$ converges. But $\sum \left(\dfrac{1}{n^{6/5}}\right)^{5/6}=\sum \dfrac{1}{n}$ diverges.